# Magnetic torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Consider the loop of wire in Figure 29.25a. Imagine it is pivoted along side 4, which is parallel to the z axis and fastened
so that side 4 remains fixed and the rest of the loop hangs vertically in the gravitational field of the Earth but can rotate
around side 4 (Fig. 29.25b). The mass of the loop is 50.0 g, and the sides are of lengths a 5 0.200 m and b 5 0.100 m.
The loop carries a current of 3.50 A and is immersed in a vertical uniform magnetic field of magnitude 0.010 0 T in the
positive y direction (Fig. 29.25c). What angle does the plane of the loop make with the vertical?

The following link has the images and solution for this problem

https://mytextbookswheniwantem.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/physics-chapter-29-magnetic-fields-pp-865-8971.pdf

I don't understand why the gravitational torque causes a rotation in the counterclockwise direction and I'm also confused about determining the sign of the gravitational torque, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. The information needed to understand your question should be contained in the question, not in a link. ... The torques are calculated *around side 4*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have annotated the last diagram.

[image]

Just go back to basics.
As seen the weight of the loop produces an anti-clockwise torque about pivot $4$.
The magnitude of this torque is the force $mg$ (weight of loop) times the perpendicular distance from the line of action of the pivot $\frac b2 \sin \theta$ which is the magnitude of the cross product $\vec r \times m\vec g$.
If you curl the fingers of your right hand in an anti-clockwise direction your thumb will be pointing out of the screen and this is the direction of the torque $\hat k$ ie in the positive z-direction.